# How to periodically check isCancelled() inside doInBackground() of AsyncTask and return if needed ?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timertask

I saw and read many post and the doc. I understand one can insert a few isCancelled(); in between some code blocks. What about a bigger workload that cannot be split into parts like Url fetching ?

I tried this dummy project to try to find a solution : while the asynctask is working, I want to check periodically the isCancelled() and skip all what is left in doInBackground() .

I tried this :

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    strUrlBase = "http://www.legorafi.fr/2012/12/20/portrait-benoit-le-fameux-ami-noir-de-tous-les-racistes/";
    if (fgDebugLocal){Log.i(tagLocal, tagLocal + "strUrlBase = " + strUrlBase);};
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                if (fgDebugLocal){Log.e(tagLocal, tagLocal + "timer asyncTask : isCancelled true" );};
                timer.cancel();
                return;
            } else {
                if (fgDebugLocal){Log.e(tagLocal, tagLocal + "timer asyncTask : isCancelled FALSE" );};
            }
        }
    },0, 100);


    for (int i = 0; i<15; i++ ) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(strUrlBase);
            https = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            https.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection = https;

            if (urlConnection.getInputStream() != null){ // Crash there :(
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                while((current=reader.read())!=-1){
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }
                strJson = new String (baf.toByteArray());
                if (fgDebugLocal){Log.i(tagLocal, tagLocal + "check le gorafi number "+i+" - " + strJson.substring(0, 100));};

                https.disconnect();
            } else {
                if (fgDebugLocal){Log.i(tagLocal, "urlConnection.getInputStream() != null");};
                fgErrorConn = true;
                varResultRequest = -1;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (fgDebugLocal){Log.i(tagLocal, "IOException = "+e.getMessage());};
            fgErrorPb = true;
            varResultRequest =0;
            //publishProgress(100);
        }
    }
    varResultRequest = 1;
    return null;
}
```

The timertask correctly detect the value of isCancelled() but I can't find a way to act after that. Any idea ? or any other way ?

Ty

Comment: The `cancel()` method takes a boolean argument that specifies whether the thread should be interrupted, which will cause all running I/O operations to be aborted.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel method is public, so you can override it. Inside your custom implementation you can first: call base version, then abort any pending http connection. You must be carefull because cancel will be called possibly from GUI thread, but I suppose it should work.

Comment: I get the general idea. But that implies 2 things : I must hold references (on the httpsconnection) at the scope level of the activity which executed the asynctask. Second, you see no solution to get a periodically checking ?

Comment: You dont need to put those references to your activity class, cancel method to be implemented is in AsyncTask. Move `HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;` to your AsyncTask implementing class. IMO there is no need for periodic checking of cancellation.

Comment: "cancel method to be implemented is in AsyncTask" ofc, i am stupid. 
We see need to periodic checking because we want to be able to relaunch the task at user's will. The doInBackground() runs until it finishes or if the developer inserted isCancelled() {break}. And the next AsynTask does not seem to start before the cancelled one terminates (the cancelled one terminates with onCancelled() but still run all the doInBackground)

Comment: Calling `urlConnection.disconnect()` inside custom `AsyncTask.cancel` should stop http connection quite fast. You should of course check if AsyncTask was cancelled right after blocking `urlConnection.getInputStream()`, and return from doInBackground. You can also post runnable on Handler inside AsyncTask.cancel, which will start another AsyncTask - even with some small delay. This way your doInBackground does not have to end. Also since API11, asynctasks are by default executed serially.

Comment: The `cancel()` method takes a boolean argument that specifies whether the thread should be interrupted, which will cause all running I/O operations to be aborted.

Comment: @corsair992 I tried to use cancel(true) to no effect, my url fetching keeps going on with a smirk on their faces

Comment: @Poutrathor: This only interrupts current I/O, not if it starts later. You need to add a manual check before it to ensure that it has not already been cancelled.

Comment: so i am stucked to my issue, i can periodically checked isCancelled() inside the timer (see code), but I don't know how to use that information to make a break inside doInBackground()   :(

Comment: @Poutrathor: Check in the `doInBackground()` method itself, instead of a using a `Timer`?

Comment: @corsair992 It's exactly what I want to do : have a periodic check inside doInbackground() for any asynctask i could wrote. Thus a timer. Now, I am stuck to skip the doInBackground() code as one can do with *only one* check : if (isCancelled() ) break;

Comment: @Poutrathor: There is no need for any periodic checks from another thread (that the timer uses), nor can anything be done that way. Just adding _one_ check _before_ performing the network request and canceling with interrupting enabled is sufficient.

Comment: because I want a solution for **any** AsyncTask, network is just an example. That means for each asynctask a developper wrote, the interruption should be carefully though and planned. Moreover, since they might be run serially, if there is one work taking much time (or failing) like a bad http connection, you cannot start another asynctask : you have to wait for that specific line of code to finish and the next check to be reached.

Comment: @Poutrathor: Then you need to check for cancellation at strategic points _inside_ your code. This can never be accomplished in a generic manner from another thread/timer.